# Replace function - no overload method error C# - Trying to remove section in string

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, foreach

I am trying to create urls from JSON.

The 'Input' data that is being received from JSON starts with -sm which I am trying to replace with nothing ""(essentially remove it).

When using the Replace function it is coming up with a no overload method error. How do I avoid this or how can I frame this code properly so there is no error? I want to remove sm- from all Input data.

My code so far:

```
        List<string> url = new List<string>();

        //Loop which adds Input and signature to array
        foreach (JObject item in jArray)
        {

            url.Add("https://" + (string)item.SelectToken("Input").Replace("sm-", "") + ".com/?sig=" + (string)item.SelectToken("signature"));
        }
```

Exact Message: CS1501 No overload for method 'Replace' takes two arguments

Comment: Stop using method chains and debug every step of your program to understand what's happening.

Comment: What do you mean by "to frame URLs"?

Comment: Apparently `SelectToken` does not return a `String` value - or it returns a non-`String` value which supports implicit conversion to `String`.

Comment: Please read [ask] and post an [mcve]. Also post the exact error message. Is it a compile or run-time error?

Comment: I have added the exact message to the thread

Comment: you should debug this line (string)item.SelectToken("Input")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(string)item.SelectToken("Input").Replace("sm-", "")`

needs to be

`((string)item.SelectToken("Input")).Replace("sm-", "")`

You could also split the code into separate statements to make it easy to find issues and easy to debug.

```cs
var urls = new List<string>();

var json = "[{\"Input\": \"sm-a\", \"signature\":\"sig1\"}, {\"Input\": \"sm-b\", \"signature\":\"sig2\"} ]";

var jArray = JArray.Parse(json);
foreach (JObject item in jArray)
{
    //Error handling missing
    var inputToken = (string)item.SelectToken("Input");
    var input = inputToken.Replace("sm-", "");
    var signature = (string)item.SelectToken("signature");

    urls.Add("https://" + input + ".com/?sig=" + signature);
}

//urls
//"https://a.com/?sig=sig1"
//"https://b.com/?sig=sig2"
```

Answer (score 0):

- The `.SelectToken` method returns a `JToken` value, not a `String` value.
- The `JToken` type <del>supports implicit conversion to `String` values, that's why you were able to use the returned `JToken` value *as though it were* a string</del>.

  - Correction: the `JToken` type only supports implicit conversion *from* a string. In your case your code was actually implicitly calling `JToken.ToString()` via the `+(String,Object)` operator.
- However relying on implicit calls `JToken.ToString()` is not a good idea, so check `JToken.Type` first - and you can reduce it all to a single Linq expression:

```
List<string> urls = jArray
    .Select( item => ( input: item.SelectToken( "Input" ), sig: item.SelectToken( "signature" ) ) )
    .Where( t => t.input.Type == JTokenType.String && t.sig.Type == JTokenType.String  )
    .Select( t => ( input: (JValue)t.input, sig: (JValue)t.sig ) )  // `JTokenType.String` implies `jtoken is JValue`
    .Select( t => ( input: t.input.ToString(), sig: t.sig.ToString() ) )
    .Select( t => "https://" t.input + ".com/?sig=" + t.sig )
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Casting JToken to string is official: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm. Also, why wouldn't it be a good idea? It's a json text. All tokens are strings. They can become something else, but they all are strings at heart.

Comment: @tymtam Ah, I forgot about the explicit conversion (though that's the same as `ToString()`, no?). Anyway, the problem with doing an unconditional conversion from `JToken` to `String` is that _if_ the `JToken` is a JSON object then the returned string should not be treated as a string-value as it will contain rendered JSON which should not have `Replace` called on it because that may invalidate the JSON (e.g. if any matches are in key names).